# getting 3 Pid's from one fork process?

Tags: c, fork, pid

```
void main(){
    if ((the_pid = fork())==0){
        printf("hello from child \n");
        printf("mypid is %d \n", getppid());
    }else{
        cpid = wait(NULL);//wait for child
        printf("parent says hello \n");
        printf("mypid is %d and my child's is %d \n", getppid(), cpid);
    }
}
```

the output

```
hello from child 
mypid is 3627100 
parent says hello 
mypid is 3554718 and my child's is 3627102
```

To my understanding, shouldn't the output have two unique pid's and with the child's pid being repeated ? Why did I get 3 supposed processes from single fork call?
any explanation is greatly apreciated

Comment: No. With a parent and child, there are 3 numbers: parent's pid, parent's parent pid, and child's pid. You're calling getppid instead of calling getpid where you wish to print the current process' pid. getppid gets the current process' parent pid.

Comment: `getpid` gets the pid. `getppid` geths the ppid. These are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Holt got the right answer i was using getppid() and when changed with getpid() it worked as expected ! thank you so much